# Create Spotify Playlist from List of Albums

Tags: list, spotify

I have a long-running list of favorite albums. I know sites like www.spotmysongs.com will take a text file of a list of artists and song titles and create a playlist out of them on Spotify, but I'd like to do the same with a list of albums, without taking the time to list every track on the album.

For example I want to have it say:

Daft Punk   Random Access Memories
Cults      Cults

and have it load those two whole albums together into a playlist. Any idea if this is possible or how to do it?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea. What have you already tried?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want done? I am able to with only a few clicks add an album to a playlist. Do you want some program to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a request to http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album?q=daft%20punk%20random%20access%20memories

http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:album:4m2880jivSbbyEGAKfITCa&extras=track to get the tracks on that album.

As for programmatically adding them to a playlist, there is currently no official way of doing this. However, here is a hack you can use by opening up the web player in the devtools console. The example code will create a playlist and add a track. You could combine this with the above steps.

```
window.frames[0].require("$api/models", function(models) {
  models.Playlist.create("My cool playlist").done( function(playlist) {
    playlist.load("tracks").done( function(){
      playlist.tracks.add( models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:3KRAqo71NrfR1UCa34JEsy").done(function(){
      })
    })
  })
})
```

You could write a browser extension to do this. Or, supposing you had a large JSON list of tracks that you want to append, you could modify the above example to add all the tracks sequentially.

Alternately, you could try using something like https://github.com/liesen/spotify-api-server, until Spotify gets their act together and gives you an official API.

Comment: basically i have a list of favorite albums of the last ten years and I want to turn it into a Spotify playlist. Ideally, I'd be able to just put a spreadsheet together with the name of the artist and the name of the album, and have it somehow turned into a playlist using the Spotify API.

Comment: Ah, cool. I updated my response with more information on how you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would enter a new answer that works better now that the spotify web api is available. You can now make supported API calls to [create a playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/create-playlist/) and [add tracks to a playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/).